# Если слово спикер употреблено по отношению к женщине, его можно не склонять?

Tags: грамматика, склонение, род

Прочитал в [статье](http://tvrain.ru/articles/putin_poprosil_sovet_federatsii_otmenit_postanovlenie_ob_ispolzovanii_armii_v_ukraine-370525/):

> Путин направил соответствующее письмо спикер верхней палаты Валентине Матвиенко перед отлетом в Вену...

Сначала был уверен, что опечатка. Потом подумал, может новое правило или тенденция есть, что 
названия должностей/профессий, которые можно употреблять по отношению к обоим полам и которые обычно относят ко второму склонению, можно не склонять в случае их употребления по отношению к женскому полу (по аналогии с несклоняемыми женскими именами, оканчивающимися на согласную).

Итак, это опечатка (должно было быть *спикеру*) или так тоже можно теперь?

Comment: Это точно опечатка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добрый день, Армен!

Можно сказать только «спи́кер**у**», это безусловно опечатка.

Comment: все верно. кроме того современный (разговорный) русский язык в силу своего устройства не подразумевает свободного использования несклоняемых слов. в речевой практике они имеют тенденцию заменяться другими.

Comment: The same as `Профессору Ивановой`, `Водителю Жириновской` etc